# In spring security how to implement both SAML and custom authentication handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml

I am implementing three types of authentication mechanisms they are SAML and two custom authentication. So, how can I implement a filter based on a header it'll detect the authentication type and it'll route to the appropriate authentication mechanism.

1. `SAML`: In case of SAML if the cookie is having a key as `saml` then SAML authentication has to happen. In SAML authentication also whenever the user login happens I am inserting a cookie with the name saml in the browser and for further requests I need to invoke a REST API by passing `saml` cookie value and check whether the authentication is valid or not.
2. `Custom authentication`: If the cookie key is having `token1` or `token2` then do the custom authentication which involves calling a Rest API by passing the token and check the user is valid or not.

I know about SAML with spring security but as I explained in SAML how we can do the rest API call and implement a filter that invoke an appropriate authentication mechanism how we can achieve this. Is there any reference which could help fr the above scenario .

Comment: Could you please provide a little more details about the SAML authentication? I mean what is the third application you are going to integrate etc.

Comment: @Shakthifuture In SAML if saml cookie/header is not present then login has to happen, once the login is success I will add a cookie(session index) in the browser. So, for further request, I'll be receiving the saml token(which is session index). So, after receiving the saml token which is in the header, I will call a REST API by passing saml token and validate the response. This is the flow I am following. I don't want maintain the session at server side(spring security microservice should be stateless).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Spring Security [AuthenticationManagerBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.20.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html). Create a security configuration with three autowired autentication provider defined elsewhere

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider1 customProvider1;

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider2 customProvider2;

@Autowired
private SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlProvider;
```

and then using the AuthenticationManagerBuilder just add them

```
authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customProvider1);
authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customProvider2);
authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(samlProvider);
```

For a complete example you can see [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Azure for SAML authentication. Follow this way to implement custom and saml authentication.

1. First, implement Simple JWT token authentication using spring security. I hope using this **user can do authentication** with `username` and `password`.
2. Implement SAML authentication, I am assuming you are using Azure. this azure will return one token.
3. Pass azure token from frontend to rest API. Validate this token using **azure API** with help of `RestTemplate`. if the token is valid, then create normal spring jwt token.

Now actually you are maintaining **single token** for all authentication.